# Can I make a latch using 2 AND gates, instead of NAND gates?

Tags: circuit-design, flipflop, sequential-logic

I have seen that, generally, a simple latch is made using either 2 NAND gates or 2 NOR gates.

Can I make a latch using 2 AND gates ?[image]

Comment: Write down the truth table for each case (using NAND, NOR and AND). Look at the behavior. Sure you can make it but will it work as a latch? What do you think.

Comment: Yes I did that. And I have seen that AND gates won't work. But I am not able to understand that why it's not working.

Comment: AND gates are exactly like 1 bit multiplication. If you multiply anything by 0, it becomes 0. How do you propose to make anything other than 0 if either of the Q and Q' are 0? - I'll ask my question differently, how do you propose to make 1*0, 0*1, 0*0, to give an answer other than 0? Because if you don't then they will both converge to 0*0 and get stuck. - This is your latch in pseudocode: `Q = RQ', Q' = SQ`, can you see for yourself that if Q becomes 0, then Q' becomes 0, which forces Q and Q' to be stuck at 0?

Comment: its not working cz nand gate is not and gate ....

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer is that you can't make a latch from just AND gates because it won't work. You can't do it with just OR gates either.

Now, **demonstrating** that it doesn't work is a great homework question and I don't want to rob you of that learning experience. Make a truth table and figure out how the next output values will depend on the input values and the previous output values.